# the problem with smtp phpmailer that Could not authenticate

Tags: javascript, php, html, smtp, phpmailer

I have a problem with phpmailer, I have the correct SMPT server data and also the username and password, but it still marks me an error in the credentials like this SMTP Error: Could not authenticate., this is my code

---

```
<?php
            require 'dbConnect.php';    
            require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
            require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
            require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
            
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
            
            if(isset($_POST['email'])){
              
                $email= $_POST['email'];
                $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                    $ran=rand(100000,999999);
                    $que = "UPDATE users SET otp_code='$ran' WHERE email ='$email'";
                    $rest = mysqli_query($conn, $que);
                    if($rest){
                        $mail = new PHPMailer();        
                        $mail->isSMTP(); 
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
                        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = "true"; 
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                        $mail->Port = "587"; // or 465
                        $mail->Username = "nanaqahesh@gmail.com";
                        $mail->Password = '*********';
                        $mail->Subject = "Test Email Using PHPMailer";
                        $mail->SetFrom("intisarraed123@gmail.com");
                        $mail->Body = "Hi, we are the MED ID team \n We inform you that you have been accepted to be part of MED ID \n Please login using your practice id and password";
                        $mail->AddAddress('intisa54@gmail.com');
                        if($mail->send()){   
                            header("location:login2.php");
                            }else{
                                echo "Error...!";
                            }
                            $mail->smtpClose();
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "there are a problem in update";
                    }   
                }
                else{ 
                    echo "error";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

---

Comment: [Search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+gmail+could+not+authenticate), base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) which covers this exact issue in great detail.

Comment: In your gmail, did you allow less secure apps to have access to your email??